# concatenate input variable in oracle alter command while connecting oracle from linux

Tags: linux, oracle

I am trying to add the datafile in oracle tablespace by using below code but getting the error : ORA-02140 : Invalid tablespacename
Please refer output3 for creation of datafile:

```
for i in `echo $output1 | tr ' ' '\n' | tr '\n' ' '`;
do
echo $i;    **#Its printing tablespace name like SYSTEM**
output2=`sqlplus -s usr/pwd as sysbackup <<END2
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200
set head off;
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME ||','|| ROUND (SUM (BYTES) / 1048576) FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = '${i}' GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME;
exit;
END2`

**#output2 is printing tablespace name and total tablespace size like SYSAUX 2048**

echo $output2 | tr ' ' '\n' > test.csv


while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2
do
echo $col2
fiftin_per=$((col2/15))
echo $fiftin_per  **#Feteched column2 from csv file which contains total tablespace space and calculated 15 per of it**
if [[ "${fiftin_per}" -gt "${avail_space}" ]];
then
echo "Assign to manual queue as required space is not available on mount point."
else
var='/'
dfname=".data00"
random_val=`shuf -i 100000000-1000000000 -n 1`
ext=".dbf"
fname="'$mount_name$var${i}$random_val$ext'"
echo $fname  **#printing datafilename like \oradata\fname\.dbf**
echo ${i}
output3=`sqlplus -s usr/pwd as sysbackup <<END2
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200
set head off;
DECLARE
var varchar(50);
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line("Value of i"||${i});
END;
/
exit;
END2`
echo $output3  **#Trying to add datafile but getting error ORA-02140**
fi
done < test.csv
done
```

I am getting below output, I am not able to pass linux variable in select command.Please refer output2 for same. But when I am trying to pass same variable from linux for loop to alter command or dbms_output.put_line getting error : PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SYSAUX' not allowed in this context ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
Output : 
/oradata01/POCDB/data/system01.dbf
/oradata01/POCDB/data
208958
SYSAUX TEST5
SYSAUX
2048
136
' /oradata01/POCDB/data/SYSAUX465368588.dbf'
dbms_output.put_line('Value of i'||SYSAUX); 

 PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SYSAUX' not allowed in this context ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Please post examples of the console output and output files in your question. Do NOT post screenshots; copy/paste and format the text, please.

Comment: @pmdba : Added the output

Comment: I meant the _actual_ output, not a description of the output. Your error indicates that there is an invalid tablespace name (${i}), but you haven't shown us what actual tablespace names are being created. We can't tell you what's wrong if we can't see the actual DDL commands that were executed.

Comment: Just a side note, you could remove the `'||$fname||'` part of the  `alter tablespace||' '||${i}||' add datafile '||$fname||' size '||${fiftin_per}||'m autoextend off maxsize 30720m';` command and Oracle will pick a unique file name for you.  And do you really want a single datafile to grow up to around 30,720 MB?

Comment: @MarkStewart : I tried to do that but getting invalid file name.(ORA-02236)

Comment: @pmdba : I have edited my question with updated code as well as output which I am getting,  please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have declared the variables as follows:

```
output3=`sqlplus -s usr/pwd as sysbackup <<END2
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200
set head off;
DECLARE
var varchar(50):='${i}';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line("Value of i"||var);
END;
/
exit;
END2`

output : Its printing the tablespace name which I am getting from linux loop
```

Comment: So, is it working now?  I noticed in your Output in your question has a leading blank in the file path  `' /oradata01/POCDB/data/SYSAUX465368588.dbf'`,  Looks like you fixed the `PLS-00357` error, right?

Comment: @MarkStewart   Yes, Its fixed!

Comment: Great!  You can go ahead and accept your own answer, via the "Accept" link by your answer.  That is so that people looking for questions with no *accepted* answers can ignore your question.  Thanks!